# Adding a newline (line break) to a Powershell script

Tags: powershell, newline, string-interpolation

I have a script I am running in Powershell, and I want to be able to put a line in my resulting text file output between the ccript name and the script content itself.

Currently, from the below, the line `$str_msg = $file,[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($file.FullName)` is what I need, but I need a line to separate `$file` and the result of the next expression. How can I do this?

```
foreach ($file in [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles($sqldir,"*.sql", 
  [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories))
{
  $file = [System.IO.FileInfo]::new($file);


  $Log.SetLogDir("");
  $str_msg = $file,[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($file.FullName);


  $Log.AddMsg($str_msg);
  Write-Output $str_msg;


  # ...

}
```

Answer (score 10):

- `$str_msg = $file,[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($file.FullName)` doesn't create a *string*, it **creates a 2-element *array*** (`[object[]]`), composed of the `$file` `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instance, and the string with the contents of that file.
- Presumably, the `.AddMsg()` method expects a single string, so PowerShell *stringifies* the array in order to convert it to a single string; **PowerShell stringifies an array by *concatenating the elements with a single space as the separator*** by default; e.g.:
  `[string] (1, 2)` yields `'1 2'`.

Therefore, it's best to **compose `$str_msg` as a *string* to begin with, with an explicit newline as the separator**, e.g.:

```
$strMsg = "$file`r`n$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($file.FullName))"
```

Note the use of escape sequence `` "`r`n" `` to produce a CRLF, the Windows-specific newline sequence; on Unix-like platforms, you'd use just `` "`n" `` (LF).

.NET offers a cross-platform abstraction, `[Environment]::NewLine`, which returns the platform-appropriate newline sequence (which you could alternatively embed as `$([Environment]::NewLine)` inside `"..."`).

An alternative to string interpolation is to use `-f`, the string-formatting operator, which is based on the .NET `String.Format()` method:

```
$strMsg = '{0}{1}{2}' -f $file, 
                        [Environment]::NewLine, 
                        [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($file.FullName)
```

Comment: Great answer. Mine worked when I tested it in a console by directly displaying the content of the array, but it is probably just the way powershell serializes arrays. This solves the root issue of OP.

Comment: Thanks, @LéoD. Yes, in the console the elements of an array are output on individual lines, but in the context of to-string conversion / string interpolation that works differently.

Answer (score 8):

Backtick-r+backtick-n will do a carriage return with a new line in PS. You could do a Get-Content of your $file variable as a new array variable, and insert the carriage return at a particular index:

Example file: test123.txt

If the file contents were this:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

Store the contents in an array variable so you have indices

```
[Array]$fileContent = Get-Content C:\path\to\test123.txt
```

To add a carriage return between line2 and line3:

```
$fileContent2 = $fileContent[0..1] + "`r`n" + $fileContent[2]
```

Then output a new file:

```
$fileContent2 | Out-File -FilePath C:\path\to\newfile.txt
```

Comment: Helpful, but note that a CR (carriage return) in isolation is _not_ treated as a newline (line break) - you need `\`r\`n` (CRLF) on Windows, and `\`n` (LF) on Unix - though PowerShell itself understands either format on both platforms. Also, Léo D.'s answer doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the **carriage return** powershell special character, which is "`r".

Use it like this to add a carriage return in your line :

```
$str_msg = $file,"`r",[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($file.FullName);
```

Check [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-6) to have more details on Poewershell special characters.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this, and it is still outputing without a new line. I've also tried an "n" instead of an "r". $str_msg = $file,"`r",[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($file.FullName);

Comment: A CR (carriage return) in isolation is _not_ treated as a newline (line break). Instead of building a single string with an embedded newline, you're creating a 3-element array - and the very fact that an _array_ is being used is voot89's problem to begin with.